# Wiremock Placeholder isn't recognized

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I tried with the following json but the wiremock doesn't recognize my change. I read the documentation of wiremock and I saw that they said: JSON equality matching is based on JsonUnit and therefore supports placeholders. I also tried with both JDK 8 and JDK 13 but both are not working

Below is the detail

```
    "method" : "POST",
    "bodyPatterns" : [{
      "equalToJson" : {
        "recipient": {
           "address": {
              "city": "Bellevue",
              "postalCode": "52031",
              "countryCode": "US"
           }
        },
        "sender": {
           "address": {
              "city": "",
              "postalCode": "",
              "countryCode": "HK"
           }
        },
        "shipDate": "${json-unit.any-string}",
        "accountNumber": {
           "key": ""
        }
      },
```

Result when running selenium test with mock (I executed mock via `java -jar tmp/wiremock.jar --global-response-templating --root-dir ./mock --port 1337` ):

```
                                                           |
{                                                          | {                                                   <<<<< Body does not match
  "recipient" : {                                          |   "recipient" : {
    "address" : {                                          |     "address" : {
      "city" : "Bellevue",                                 |       "city" : "Bellevue",
      "postalCode" : "52031",                              |       "postalCode" : "52031",
      "countryCode" : "US"                                 |       "countryCode" : "US"
    }                                                      |     }
  },                                                       |   },
  "sender" : {                                             |   "sender" : {
    "address" : {                                          |     "address" : {
      "city" : "",                                         |       "city" : "",
      "postalCode" : "",                                   |       "postalCode" : "",
      "countryCode" : "HK"                                 |       "countryCode" : "HK"
    }                                                      |     }
  },                                                       |   },
  "shipDate" : "${json-unit.any-string}",                  |   "shipDate" : "May-26-2020",
  "accountNumber" : {                                      |   "accountNumber" : {
    "key" : ""                                             |     "key" : ""
  }                                                        |   }
}                                                          | }
                                                           |
```

Can anybody make some suggestions here. Thank you for reading my question

Comment: Are you using the latest version and the jre8 variant?

Comment: @Tom I used jdk 8 and jdk 13. I read the documentation and they said that jre is built inside

Comment: @SangMai Are you using the latest version of WireMock, and jre8 variant of the standalone WireMock .jar?

Answer (score 1):

you have to enable the placeholder as below and you should make sure you are using the jre-standalone jar. you seem to be using the normal standalone jar

`"enablePlaceholders" : true`

Comment: yes, I am. But I don't know how to do that :D it is good if you can guide us here

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/61352988/2621917 and used the suggestion: Update Wiremock. My version had placeholders documented, but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of "${json-unit.any-string}" is right. But placeholder  works when the right dependency is used.

Using dependency `com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8` worked for me.

Refer https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/ for more info. This would mention the following note

> Placeholders are only available in the jre8 WireMock JARs, as the JsonUnit library requires at least Java 8.